# How to create a vector of std::ofstream s and write the stream to different text files

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am just trying to write some numbers to a few different files using an `std::vector` of `std::ofstream`s. My program is compiling and running and the files are getting generated but there is no text in my files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    auto num_components = 3;
    std::vector<std::ofstream> files_to_be_written;
    files_to_be_written.resize(num_components);

    for (auto i = 0; i < num_components; ++i){
      std::string file_name = "text" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
      files_to_be_written.emplace_back(std::ofstream{ file_name });
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data_to_be_written;
    data_to_be_written.resize(num_components);
    data_to_be_written[0].push_back(1);
    data_to_be_written[0].push_back(2);
    data_to_be_written[0].push_back(3);
    data_to_be_written[1].push_back(4);
    data_to_be_written[1].push_back(5);
    data_to_be_written[1].push_back(6);
    data_to_be_written[2].push_back(7);
    data_to_be_written[2].push_back(8);

    for (auto& it : data_to_be_written)
    {
        auto idx = &it - &data_to_be_written[0];
        for (auto i = it.begin(); i != it.end(); ++i)
        {
            files_to_be_written[idx] << *i << "\n";
        }
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < num_components; ++i){
        files_to_be_written[i].close();
    }
}
```

I am unsure where I am making the mistake.

Comment: While I'm not sure where is the problem, I'd like to point to a couple of places that look weird. Iterate over an integer, instead of `for (auto& it : data_to_be_written)` and subsequent pointer magic to get the index. Once you change vector to, say, deque and you're doomed. Also, close is not necessary at the end of main

Comment: I also guess that moving std::ofstream objects into a vector does something unintended with your streams. Try smart pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> auto num_components = 3;
> std::vector<std::ofstream> files_to_be_written;
> files_to_be_written.resize(num_components);
> ```

Since you call `std::vector::resize()` here, this creates three new empty `std::ofstream` elements in the vector. Then you append three more `std::ofstream` objects to the back of the vector with `std::vector::emplace_back()` using the file paths. You end up with 6 elements in the vector.

The problem is you're writing only to the first three `std::ofstream` elements in this bit of code:

```
for (auto& it : data_to_be_written)
{
    auto idx = &it - &data_to_be_written[0];
    for (auto i = it.begin(); i != it.end(); ++i)
    {
        files_to_be_written[idx] << *i << "\n";
    }
}
```

The solution is simple. Replace

```
files_to_be_written.resize(num_components);
```

with

```
files_to_be_written.reserve(num_components);
```

[`std::vector::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) doesn't add any new elements to the vector, but simply allocates memory for them.